# What's behind this GPT header value?

Tags: guid, boot, disk, disk-partitioning, uefi

This dump is the output of a `dd if=/dev/sda bs=512 | hexdump -C` on a 2GiB hard disk (`.vdi`, on Virtual Box) onto which a `GUID Partition Table` was written using `cfdisk`. This is what `LBA 1` (the GPT header logical block) looks like:

```
45 46 49 20 50 41 52 54 | EFI signature
00 00 01 00             | GPT version
5c 00 00 00             | GPT header size
f8 8f 25 0d             | CRC32 (header)
00 00 00 00             | reserved
01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 | current LBA (this is LBA 1) 
ff ff 3f 00 00 00 00 00 | backup LBA (last LBA on disk)
00 08 00 00 00 00 00 00 | first LBA available for partitions
de ff 3f 00 00 00 00 00 | last LBA available for partitions
a1 4b 7c df ca 02 95 4c | disk's GUID [1/2]
98 16 bb f0 73 d3 c8 0c | disk's GUID [2/2]
02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 | partition entries' first LBA
80 00 00 00             | total amount of partition entries
80 00 00 00             | size of a single partition entry
86 d2 54 ab             | CRC32 (entries)
00 ..                   | zeroed out until next LBA
```

This header states there are 80h (128d) partition entries, each being 128 bits long, so entries start from `LBA 2` and span for 16KiB or 32 sectors (512B per sector in this disk), meaning from `LBA 02h` to `LBA 21h`.

**Why is `LBA 800h` reported as the first available LBA for partitions instead of `LBA 22h`, the next after partition entries? Aren't entries and actual partitions stored contiguously on disk?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it looks like this is a `cfdisk`-specific behavior. I wiped out the GPT and wrote it back twice using `gdisk` and `parted`, both of which placed the Partition Entry Array's starting point in `LEA 22h`, as I was expecting. Note however that having the actual partitions start further in the disk is perfectly acceptable, since the UEFI 2.6 standard only dictates they don't start any sooner than `LEA 22h`.